# Custom Deserialization: use JsonConverter or custom override of Deserialize method?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

My C# model `Person` has properties that don't map nicely to the JSON I am getting from a RESTful request.

C# Model:

```
class Person {
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last  { get; set; }
}
```

JSON Response:

```
{
    "customer_first_name": "foo",
    "customer_last_name": "bar"
}
```

So when I deserialize the JSOn to a Person model/object I need to map `customer_first_name` to `First` and so on (am I correct?). Should I be using a JsonConverter to achieve this? Or custom override of Deserialize method? Or something else?

Comment: You can use attributes to define the JSON property names for your C# class properties. You can either use `[DataContract]` in conjunction with `[DataMember]` attributes (attributes provided by the .NET framework), or the equivalent Json.NET attribute `[JsonProperty]`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`[JsonProperty]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm#JsonPropertyAttribute) attribute.

```
class Person {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "customer_first_name")]
    public string First { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "customer_last_name")]
    public string Last  { get; set; }
}
```